# How to get an object from the database with NHibernate?

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I'm trying to get an object back from an NHibernate query.

My method is as follows:

```
public Site GetSiteByHost(string host)
{
    var result = _session.CreateCriteria<Site>()
        .Add(SqlExpression.Like<Site>(g => g.URLName, host));

    return result;
}
```

the problem is, `result` is a type of HNibernate.ICriteria.

How can I get this to return a `Site` object?

If I was doing this with LINQ to SQL it'd be something like `.FirstOrDefault()` but that's not available with NHibernate... or is it?!?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to first execute the query (by calling `List<T>()` on the criteria) before calling `FirstOrDefault`. Notice that this query might return multiple objects:

```
IEnumerable<Site> sites = _session
    .CreateCriteria<Site>()
    .Add(SqlExpression.Like<Site>(g => g.URLName, host))
    .List<Site>();
```

And you could take the first one:

```
Site result = sites.FirstOrDefault();
```

or directly:

```
public Site GetSiteByHost(string host)
{
    return _session
        .CreateCriteria<Site>()
        .Add(SqlExpression.Like<Site>(g => g.URLName, host))
        .List<Site>()
        .FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Comment: This can load more rows from the database than needed

Answer (score 1):

I think you can put a `.List<Site>()` on the end, and then do the `.FirstOrDefault()` on it.

Answer (score 1):

I believe `.UniqueResult()` is what you're after...

from the docs:

> Convenience method to return a single
>   instance that matches the query, or
>   null if the query returns no results.

Answer (score 0):

You can use linq with NHibernate. It is in the NHibernate.Linq namespace in the trunk of NHiberante.

```
return session.Query<Site>().FirstOrDefault(site => site.UrlName.Contains(host));
```

When you prefer the criteria API over Linq, you have to use `result.SetMaxResults(1).UniqueResult()` to create something equal to `IQueryable.FirstOrDefault`

Comment: If you are using NHibernate 2.1.2, you need NHibernate.LINQ from NHContrib.