# Spring.Net HibernateTemplate.Execute Clarification

Tags: nhibernate, spring.net

I am taking over a project that was written by third party consultants who have already left.

I come from EF backgournd. One of the DAO class has the following which I find very hard to get my head around on details of what is exactly happening step by step. If anyone could kindly help me to understand this code section will be much appreciated.

```
return HibernateTemplate.Execute(
                    delegate(ISession hbSession) // <<--What is this code actually trying to do?
                    {
                        string queryText = "from {0} x where x.Code = :Code";
                        queryText = string.Format(queryText, typeof(Product));

                        IQuery query = hbSession.CreateQuery(queryText);
                        query.SetParameter("Code", productCode);
                        query.SetCacheable(true);
                        query.SetCacheRegion(CoreCacheConstants.ProductQueryCacheRegion); // <-- What is this code trying to do.

                        var fund = query.UniqueResult(); // <-- Is this similar to DISTINCT keyword in LINQ?

                        if (fund == null)
                            throw new ArgumentException(String.Format("No product found with productcode: {0}", productCode: ));

                        NHibernateUtil.Initialize(((Product)Product).Details); // <--What is this code trying to do. And where is the execute method for above queries.
                        return fund;
                    }
                ) as Product
```

Basically I am confused with delegate part and why delegate is being used instead of simple query to database. And what is the benefit of above approach.

Also I cant see any nHibernate ORM mapping xml. Does Spring.NET requires mapping files in order to pass data from/to data source?In order words how does ISession knows which database to connect to and which table to use etc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what in the spring documents is referred to as [Classic Hibernate Usage](http://www.springframework.net/doc-latest/reference/html/classic-spring.html#d4e11771). It is not the currently recommended approach to work with NHibernate, which is described in the [chapter on object relational mappers](http://www.springframework.net/doc-latest/reference/html/orm.html#orm-hibernate).

The "convenient" usage of delegates here is basically done to provide the `HibernateTemplate` the means to manage a session and hand this managed session over to other custom methods (in this particular case an [anonymous method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0yw3tz5k.aspx)). (I think it's an implementation of the [visitor pattern](http://www.oodesign.com/visitor-pattern.html), btw).

Using this approach, the classic `HibernateTemplate` can provide functionality to methods it doesn't "know of", such as opening and closing sessions correctly and participating in transactions.

The query is actually being executed by `HibernateTemplate.Execute(myMethod)`; I imagine it creates and initializes a session for you, does transaction management, executes your method with the managed session and cleans everything up.

I've never used `HibernateTemplate`, but I'm sure it would require mapping files and a `SessionFactory`, so if this code is hit during execution and doesn't throw any exceptions, the configuration for those has to be there somewhere!

With respect to the questions (besides the delegate part) within your posted code: the use of `NHibernateTemplate` hasn't really got anything to do with it: you can just as well run this code in any piece of code where you've got hold of a valid `ISession` instance:

- the session executes a HQL query; this query is added to the query cache. I've never used `SetCacheRegion` myself, but apparently it gives you ["fine-grained control over query cache expiration policies"](http://www.nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#performance-querycache).
- [`query.UniqueResult`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3214264/322283)
- [`NHibernateUtil.Initialize`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3295976/what-does-nhibernateutil-initialize-do)

Comment: @Marjin, thank you for your help. How did you learn Spring.net, is there book you would recommend? Spring.net documentation assumes that reader knows callback, delegate calls etc. I'm looking for 101 with description.

Comment: Also, what is purpose of this query IQuery query = hbSession.CreateQuery(queryText). in other words why put on session instead of directly query db. I can't see advantage of storing the query itself in session.

Comment: Sadly, I can't recommend you a book on Spring.Net. Actually, I learned most from the docs, the spring.net forum and the source code. For general understanding of the spring framework, [Spring in Action](http://www.manning.com/walls3/) is a good book, but it's for Spring for Java.

Comment: Actually, this is a hql query, which nhibernate will translate into sql, execute and map to a `Product` object.

Comment: The query is executed against the session on `query.UniqueResult`, and I *assume* the last line should be `NHibernateUtil.Initialize(((Product)fund).Details);`, which will initalize `fund.Details` proxy, so that you can access the `Details` collection without getting a `LazyLoad` exception.

Comment: Hope that makes sense ... if you haven't dealt with NHibernate before it certainly looks like jibberish.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7571/discussion-between-flybyte-and-marijn)